# How to control screens on several Windows computers placed around a room?

Tags: bash, windows, display

I want to setup read-only screens around a room that displays different messages at different times. A single laptop would run a BASH script that checks the times, and decides which messages to send to which display, and when. This could either be text only (maybe a console, but with a huge font) or pictures, whichever is possible will be fine. A very basic script might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Good morning!" > /dev/screen1
echo "Please stack the blocks as high as you can!" > /dev/screen2
```

My workplace has many unused Lenovo Yogas, so I could fold back the keyboard and mount seven or eight of them around the room with just the screens showing. I don't think the workplace would allow me to remove Windows 10 from these devices.

- Text or pictures, either is fine.
- The Yogas do have HDMI ports.
- People in the room won't interact with the screens, they display information only.

The question is, how do I get text (or optionally pictures) from a BASH script on a laptop running Linux to display on these different messages or pictures on the Windows screens scattered around the room?

Comment: We have pieces of this, in that the various monitors (driven by kiosk-y machines) are tied to a webpage. The webpage has a refresh on it. And we have the ability to use scripts to update the webpage contents. By leveraging a standard browser and webpage, it is pretty easy to display whatever is needed (for example, we generate charts, or alerts, one displays the Grafana monitoring, or whatever). Different kiosks look at different webpages or pass a parameter or something. The webserver is on the linux machine that has the `bash` script in your example.

Comment: @KevinO Is there some way to set this up such that the web site data isn't publicly available on the WWW? It just closed to the seven computers accessing it?

Comment: I would presume the 7 win computers plus the linux are all on a local, non-routable subnet (e.g., 192.168), and therefore if the webserver is on the linux box, just have the windows machines look at 192.168.1.24 (or whatever).

Comment: @Kevin you've the makings of a good answer there

Comment: @Village apart from the local network restriction, apache and nginx may very well restrict access to specific IPs (or a given range) only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a simple http server on your Linux machine with a number of static html pages. Write your messages from bash to those pages directly. Open those pages in a browser on your windows machine. You can use some javascript magic to autoreload its contents when a new data is coming.

Example:

On a Linux machine:

Set up a static http server and let it serve from `/var/www/room/`:

```bsh
mkdir /var/www/room/
cd /var/www/room/
python3 -m http.server
```

Create a page `/var/www/room/index.html`:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="data">
  <!-- here will be an autoreloaded data -->
</div>
<script>
const AUTORELOAD_TIMEOUT = 1000;  // milliseconds

setInterval(async () => {
  /*
    Load data from an address after the hash-sign (#) and put it into div#data

    E.g. if the browser location is:

       http://somesite/some/path#some/file/name

    then the function will load data from the page:

       http://somesite/some/file/name

  */
  const hash = document.location.hash
  if (hash.length <= 1) {
    return
  }
  const file = hash.slice(1)
  const response = await fetch(file)
  if (response.status === 200) {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = await response.text()
  }
}, AUTORELOAD_TIMEOUT)
</script>
</body>
```

On a Windows machine:

- Open a browser at `http://your-linux-machine-ip:your-linux-machine-port/index.html#screen1`

On the Linux machine:

- Write to a file `screen1`:

```
echo "Hello, world!" > /var/www/room/screen1
```

Check out the Windows machine:

- the page should show a text `Hello, world!`

Comment: A more architecturally elegant solution would imply using websockets: a Python (or other) script can start a WebSocket server that will transit data from one or more named pipes to the clients (so the bash script will be able to do `echo "Some text" >./namedPipeN`). However, as such a solution is probably an overkill from the  profit/effort ratio perspective, I won't publish it unless somebody explicitly states they would like to see it.